# Streamer w. ~5k followers. Trying to scrape data from a table using JS?

Tags: javascript, html-table, streaming

I'm a mid-size streamer who recently picked up the loyalty system from StreamLabs which includes points that each user accumulates for being in the stream. However, I can't use my own JavaScript to customize the points system and add new functionality, so I want to use another open source twitch bot (Phantombot) in conjunction with the StreamLabs system. My viewers are too attached to the StreamLabs overlay, so I can't just go the pure Phantombot route.

I have over 1,000 users that all have their own points that need to be transferred over. StreamLabs does not offer a clean way to export an excel document that contains users with their point values. I inspected the page that lists all of the points, and it is structured like this:

```
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td class="table_name"> String </td> <!-- The name of the user -->
    <td class="table__message"> Number </td> <!-- The user's amount of points -->
    <td class="table__controls">
        <div class="pane-dropdown">
            <a class="pane-dropdown__toggle"> <!-- The cog opens the dropdown list -->
                <span>
                    <i class="fa fa-cog"> <!-- There she is. -->
                        ::before
                    </i>
                </span>
             </a>
             <div class="pane-dropdown__menu" style="display: none;">
                 <span>
                     <ul class="pane-dropdown__list">
                         <li>
                             <a class="pane-dropdown__link">Edit Points</a>
                         <li>
                         <li>
                             <a class="pane-dropdown__link warn">Block User</a>
                         </li>
                         <li>
                             <a class="pane-dropdown__link warn">Reset Points</a>
                         </li>
                     </ul>
                 </span>
             </div>
         </div>
     </td>
 </tr>
<!-- More table rows for each user -->
```

Here is a link to what the page looks like:

[image: https://imgur.com/JSBFHYi]

Is there a way for me to cycle through each page, fetch the points for each user, and put the information in a meaningful format, such as an excel document?

I know basic JavaScript that I mostly taught myself, and have good intuition - but a project like this is completely beyond my skillset. I was thinking about using a for loop to push to an array an object for each user, with a property for points and a property for name, then exporting those two properties all to a .csv document. However, I have no idea how to do that, or if it's even possible (but if it's popsicle, it's possible) so I think that it's possible. Any nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

My thoughts are that when constructing the script, the classes table_name and table__message might be a good place to start - any guidance?

Comment: Everything is possible with js... Are we talking about a simple browser script or professional serverside (nodejs) fetchings?

Comment: Have you checked the StreamLabs API ? https://dev.streamlabs.com

Comment: @Fran The streamlabs API doesn't really offer much besides donation alerts, beyond that it is pretty limited and I can't do anything with the points system that they haven't created for me themselves

Comment: @Jonas w The first one. I am just looking to cycle through the pages in my browser and collect the data, so that I can export it into PhantomBot.

Comment: @Fran Wait. I may have jumped the gun on that statement. I didn't look at the API. I'm looking now. There is a section about points. Let's see if it's helpful...

Comment: I used Ankhbot before streamlabs and still do in addition as, even after syncing my points from Ankhbot to streamlabs it doesn't count them the same way. I might need to scrap Ankhbot points but it has commands you can make available to viewers to query their current points.

Comment: @Streamer Yes, they seem to have a section for points. If possible it would be better to use API than reading the page as streamlabs webpage doesn't always show refreshed data https://dev.streamlabs.com/v1.0/reference#points

Comment: @Fran I'm the opposite. I used Streamlabs before I used anything else, so I wasn't able to export my data. I want to export my data to Phantombot. Being able to query points is useful, but in this situation I don't have a list of users to work with, unfortunately.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156537/discussion-between-streamer-and-fran).

Answer (score 1):

It seems the Streamlabs API has several options to interact with Points.

Looking through the examples, the "Group Get Points" might be what you are looking for:

```
var data = JSON.stringify(false);

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.withCredentials = true;

xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
  if (this.readyState === this.DONE) {
    console.log(this.responseText);
  }
});

xhr.open("GET", "https://streamlabs.com/api/v1.0/points/group_get_points?access_token=access_token&channel=channel&usernames=usernames");

xhr.send(data);
```

This should result in an array of users with their points, similar to this:

```
[
  {
    username: "sunny601",
    points: 94
  },
  {
    username: "sunny602",
    points: 103
  }
]
```

See the Streamlabs [**API Documentation on Points**](https://dev.streamlabs.com/v1.0/reference#points) for more details

Comment: Awesome! Questions - what should I use to run this script? There is a browser extension, right? Is there one that you recommend? Also, do you have any insight unto how I would export this into an excel document? Thanks!!!

Comment: I never used the API myself but a quick search found a fiddle example on how to store JSON as CSV you can then open in Excel. http://jsfiddle.net/hybrid13i/JXrwM/ - You can just run it locally in a custom HTML page with a single button on it, referencing a log JS file. Or Using NodeJs you could write a command line version of it I believe.

Comment: Wow. You are amazing. Is this something that I can just run in my browser? I really appreciate all the help. I just need to know where I can go/what I should use to run the script from the API and copy the data.Then I can run the conversion from JSON to CSV.

Comment: If you are looking for a free webdev IDE you can check out VS Code from Microsoft https://code.visualstudio.com/ though for this you also could just use notepad++ and run the html file directly in the browser.

Comment: It looks like I've run into another wall - the API requires an array of usernames in order for me to find their points. It sucks that there isn't a way to get an array of every user that has points. What should I do?

Comment: hmm, seeing Ankhbot can do it, I would assume you can use the twitch API to obtain all your follower's usernames and use that as the input for your Streamlabs Query https://dev.twitch.tv/docs Streamlabs aso uses the Twitch API to obtain the list of followers as it doesn't store it locally. It only stores currencies against usernames (sadly not twitch user ids) hence when people rename their twitch name, they points are gone :/

Comment: Should I be looking at display names and not regular names?

Comment: No idea, I never used any of those APIs. My Guess what ever their twitch display name is. Try one then the other. I can't even open twitch API docs in work due to firwalls.

Answer (score 0):

On browserside you could iterate over all *tr*s , and get their first and second childrens value:

```
const result =
[...document.getElementsByTagName("tr")]
 .map(el => [ el.children[0].textContent, el.children[1].textContent ])
```